# Как с помощью ajax запроса обновить частичное представление?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

```
@model WebApplication14.Domain.Concrete.ViewCurrentDisciples
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Test";
 }
<html>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
<body>
<div id="Results_Section">@{Html.RenderAction("FirstSpisok", "Test");}</div>
<div class="col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PostData()">Отправить</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if($('div[class = "col-md-4"]').is(":hidden"))
        {
            $('div[class = "col-md-4"]').slideDown(2000);
        }
    });
    function PostData() {
        var params = new Array();
        var napr = new Array();
        var testdata = {
            'Params': params,
            'Napr': napr
        }
        $('input[class = "checking"]:checked').each(function () {
            params.push($(this).val());
            napr.push($(this).attr('id'));
        })
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Test/FirstSpisok',
            data: JSON.stringify(testdata),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            async : true
        }
            );
        //$('div[class = "col-md-4"]').slideUp(2000);
        function successFunc(data) {
            console.log("sdfsdf" + data);
             $("#Results_Section").append(data);

    }
    }

    function errorFunc(errorData) {
        alert('Ошибка' + errorData.responseText);
    }
    let a = function(spec, value)
    {

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Контролер

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using WebApplication14.Models.DataBaseModel;
 using WebApplication14.Domain.Concrete;
 using WebApplication14.Domain.Abstract;
  namespace WebApplication14.Controllers
  {
  public class TestController : Controller
{

    public PartialViewResult FirstSpisok()
    {
        return PartialView(new ViewCurrentDisciples { sp = (SpecConstructor)Session["Cart"] });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FirstSpisok(ModelOfOutPut mf)
    {

            return Json(new ViewCurrentDisciples { sp = (SpecConstructor)Session["Cart"] });


    }
}
```

}

Comment: ну и вчем собственно вопрос? Ошибка тут наверно только в строке `$("Results_Section").append();` т.к. неверный селектор (должен быть или #Result_section или .Result_section) и ничего не добавляется как параметр функции append (предполагается что там будет data из responce)

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, что я хочу вернуть частичное представление обновить то, которое уже есть, после .apen() ничего не стоит так как этот вариант не работает

Comment: у вас data отправляется как string. а надо ключ-значение.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev , не обязательно http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Зачем, во втором случае, ты возвращаешь `JsonResult`?
Json, обычно, используют в том случае, когда хотят вернуть какой-то набор данных. Например, массив или объект.

Но, в твоем случае, как я понимаю, ты хочешь заменить старый контент на новый, возвращай тогда `PartialViewResult`, а потом заменяй старый html на новый с помощью функции [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Представление:

```
@model WebApplication14.Domain.Concrete.ViewCurrentDisciples
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}
<html>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
<body>
    <div id="Results_Section">@{Html.RenderAction("FirstSpisok", "Test");}</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="PostData()">Отправить</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if ($('div.col-md-4').is(":hidden")) {
                $('div.col-md-4').slideDown(2000);
            }
        });
        function PostData() {
            var params = new Array();
            var napr = new Array();
            var testdata = {
                'Params': params,
                'Napr': napr
            }
            $('input.checking:checked').each(function () {
                params.push($(this).val());
                napr.push($(this).attr('id'));
            })
            $.post('/Test/FirstSpisok', testdata).done(successFunc).fail(errorFunc);

        }
        function successFunc(data) {
            $("#Results_Section").html(data);
        }
        function errorFunc(errorData) {
            alert('Ошибка' + errorData.responseText);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication14.Models.DataBaseModel;
using WebApplication14.Domain.Concrete;
using WebApplication14.Domain.Abstract;

namespace WebApplication14.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        public PartialViewResult FirstSpisok()
        {
            return PartialView(new ViewCurrentDisciples {sp = (SpecConstructor) Session["Cart"]});
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult FirstSpisok(ModelOfOutPut mf)
        {
            //какой-то код
            return PartialView(new ViewCurrentDisciples {sp = (SpecConstructor) Session["Cart"]});
        }
    }
}
```